house water pipe is energized
this is a mobile home, the owner tried to shut off the main water and got a shock when he touched to valve, I found, with the main house breaker off and the electric meter pulled, I had 35 volts A/C to the house ground, the water pipe appears to be energized from an outside source, any thoughts on correcting this would be helpfull, thank you

Any close by neighbours?  Having the transformer/power pole checked by experts might help also.  Above or underground wires from the pole?

Any chance the shock was tested for being the same or less when the meter was pulled?

Is the incoming power provided by Meter towers, or individual meter and disconnects?  Is the ground wet from recent heavy rain?  If the power is turned off from the outside disconnect and there is still voltage showing at the water shutoff, call the power company.

This could be due to a broken ground wire at the entrance or power transformer or other issue. As you surmise, it is potentially deadly -- touch stove and sink, and get zorched, for example. Yes, get an electrician to fix this!
